# Python: rearrangement of dataframe rows based on conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Have got two input dataframe like below:
***tab_df***

```
row     table_no    table_bit   item     space
45          1           1       Melon     0.2
45          1           2       Banana    0.1
45          1           3       Banana    0.1
45          2           1       Apple     0.25
45          2           2       Apple     0.25
46          1           1       Apple     0.25
46          1           2       Orange    0.3
```

***item_df***

```
item    unique_row   count
Apple   {45,46}       {2,1}
Orange  {13,14}       {1,1}
```

**item_df description:** Each row's respective count is present in count column. Eg., row 45 holds 2 count and row 46 holds 1 count.

In `tab_df`, each item need to be arranged within the same row and should not be spread across rows. For Example, Apple is spread across row 45 and 46 which need to be rearranged. For doing so below conditions need to be considered.

1. First, in `item_df.unique_row` the row number which got lesser count in count column need to be captured. So Here, for Apple - row 46 holds lesser count as 1. So Apple in row 46 need to moved to row 45 which have max count.
2. To do so, nearest item from row45th-Apple which got same count as row46th-Apple need to be replaced as show in `output_df`.
3. Also, to keep all moved item together, other item need to be pushed. Eg., Apple is moved to row 45 replacing Melon. But since all apples need to present together intermediate items are pushed up/down within the row (like Banana moved up).

**output_df**

```
row     table_no    table_bit   item     space
45          1           1       Banana    0.1   #Pushed up to place all Apples together.
45          1           2       Banana    0.1   
45          1           3       Apple     0.25  #moved from row 46 to 45
45          2           1       Apple     0.25
45          2           2       Apple     0.25
46          1           1       Melon     0.2   #replaced for Apple 
46          1           2       Orange    0.3
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You!