# Python: Rearranging dataframe rows w.r.t another dataframe value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

input dataframe
**row_df**

```
item    uni_row     count   row
Apple   46             1    [45,46]
```

**tab_df**

```
row     table_no    table_bit   item     space
45          1           0       Lemon     0.25
45          1           1       Melon     0.2
45          1           2       Banana    0.1
45          1           3       Banana    0.1
45          2           1       Apple     0.25
45          2           2       Apple     0.25
46          1           1       Apple     0.25
46          1           2       Orange    0.3
```

Here, as per `row_df` data, 46th row Apple present in `tab_df` need to be moved to row 45(left out row value from `row_df.row` on comparing `row_df.uni_row`) replacing the `tab_df.item` which matches the respective `row_df.count` value. Selection of replacing item from `tab_df` need to figured out from the reverse order from the point where the row 45th Apple starts.

**Expected output:**

```
row     table_no    table_bit   item     space
45          1           0       Lemon     0.25
45          1           1       Apple     0.25      #rearranged
45          1           2       Banana    0.1
45          1           3       Banana    0.1
45          2           1       Apple     0.25
45          2           2       Apple     0.25
46          1           1       Melon     0.2       #rearranged
46          1           2       Orange    0.3
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: is this not a duplicate of your another question ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74056775/python-rearrangement-of-dataframe-rows-based-on-conditions

Comment: not a duplicate, just splitting up concept for ease